# Re: Handling the Error: The field RQ_REQ_STATUS cannot be used with a <folder>

Tags: vbscript, hp-quality-center

I am trying to extract requirements using the function GetChildrenList(id), the following is my code:

```
Sub Reqextraction ()
'here QC connection related code
Set rfact1 = QCConnection.ReqFactory 'creating reqfactory object
Set rfilter1 = rfact1.Filter  'filter object
rfilter("RQ_TYPE_ID") = "Functional" Or "Folder" Or "User Story"  'filtering based on type
rfilter1.KeepHierarchical = True 'hierarchy is set as true
father_id1 = 81   'manually entered Requirement id
GetChildren1 rfact1, rfilter1, father_id1 'calling this method to extract rest all req's
end sub


Sub GetChildren1(rfactr2, rfilterr2, father_idr2)
Set Childrenr1 = rfactr2.GetFilteredChildrenList(father_idr2, rfilterr2)
For Each Childr1 In Childrenr1  'Navigating to each child
MsgBox(Childr1.field("RQ_REQ_STATUS"))  'Err: The field cannot be used with the type <Folder>
MsgBox(Childr1.field("RQ_USER_TEMPLATE_16"))  'Err: the field cannot be  used with the type <Folder>
MsgBox(Childr1.field("RQ_REQ_NAME")) 'this is working fine
GetChildren1 rfactr2, rfilterr2, Childr1.ID  'calling the same method with obtained req id
Next
end sub
```

Could you please help me fix these errors?

Comment: I have bypassed the error code(for the req type folder) using if condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that Req type folder will not have status, so if the req folder that is being extracted is by passed with the help of status code using if condition...then in that case you will have all field values extracted.